# Nodes in VBox don't have the same width

Tags: java, css, javafx, width, input-field

I use a `VBox` to provide 3 Input fields.
They are all set up like this:

```
tf = new TextField();
tf.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
sp = new Spinner<Integer>(0, 3, 1);
sp.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
dp = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
dp.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf, sp, dp);
```

The width of the `TextField` and the `DatePicker` is equal. However the `Spinner` is slightly shorter.
How can I get all to the same size?

Note: Using `.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);` led to a layout Problem with the parent node (which does extend `StackPane`) of the `VBox`.

[image: VBox for the input fields]
Explination: The Component with the border extends `StackPane` and can only hold one `node`. The "node" in this case is a `VBox`, that holds the 3 Input fields and the Buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setMaxWidth` on the individual controls and call [`setFillWidth(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidthProperty) on the `VBox` itself:

```
tf = new TextField();
tf.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
sp = new Spinner<Integer>(0, 3, 1);
sp.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
dp = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
dp.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

vBox.setFillWidth(true);

vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf, sp, dp);
```